# Getting #Name? error in combobox - MS Access

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, combobox

I'm trying to set the default value of a few items on my form so I don't have to keep updating them as I scan items to a table. I have 3 comboboxes in my form and the other two are working fine (keeping the same value after record entry) but the cbx for "Equipment" is consistently giving me this error. I've tried updating field names by going from "Type" to "Equipment Type" and now to "Equipment" and that has not fixed it. I'll try to give good context below, but please let me know if there is more information you need. Thanks! --Forgot to mention that the table for equipment types has one field: "EQType" and it is set as the primary key.

VBA to set default values in comboboxes

```
Private Sub Serial_Number_AfterUpdate()

[Equipment].DefaultValue = [Equipment]
[ToTech].DefaultValue = [ToTech]
[FromTech].DefaultValue = [FromTech]

End Sub
```

Field names of the table I'm updating:

- Serial Number (Textbox)

  - Control source: Serial Number
- Equipment (Combobox)

  - Control source: Equipment
  - Row Source: SELECT EQType FROM EquipmentTypes;
- From Tech (Combobox)

  - Row Source: SELECT Roster.TechID FROM Roster;
- To Tech (Combobox)

  - Row Source: SELECT Roster.TechID FROM Roster;
- Date Added (Textbox) --Default Value
  set to "=Date()"

Information about form:

Split form, named "Transfers", Record Source = Transfers table

Comment: Try deleting the combobox and recreating.

Comment: Deleted, added via "Add Existing Fields", set row source to SELECT EquipmentTypes.EQType FROM EquipmentTypes. Still same error unfortunately

Comment: Try explicitly qualifying object name references with Me.: `Me.Equipment.DefaultValue = Me.Equipment`. Try naming control different from field, such as cbxEquip.

Comment: No luck with those changes either. I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Only other suggestion I can make is to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefaultValue` is text, so you probably miss to quote the value:

```vb
Private Sub Serial_Number_AfterUpdate()

    Me![Equipment].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![Equipment].Value & "'"
    Me![ToTech].DefaultValue = Me![ToTech].Value
    Me![FromTech].DefaultValue = Me![FromTech].Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the answer. I replaced my code with yours and it works perfectly, thank you!